# "always be" vs "is/are always"

Tags: word-order, verb-agreement

Are the following sentences grammatically correct? I think #2 is correct, but I'm not sure.

1. My room *always be* clean
2. My room *is always* clean

Comment: #2 is absolutely correct for this example, but there are other constructions in which "always be" would be correct.

Comment: I've no idea why we always say *My room is always clean*, but *My room always smells musty*. @JSBᾶngs thinks the verb usually comes *after* "always", and Colin suspects the opposite. I don't have an opinion (yet), but I think this is a much more interesting issue than the grammaticality of *My room always be clean*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your #2 is correct. There are two rules in play here:

1. The verb *to be* must agree with its subject.
2. Normally, adverbs such as *always* follow the verb *to be*.

Because of these rules, #2 is correct and #1 is an error in standard English.

However, in a different syntactic frame the sequence "always be" could be correct. For example, if we add a modal verb then the sentence becomes:

> My room **would always be** clean if I had time to clean it.

Here, the modal verb *would* blocks verb agreement, and the adverb *always* follows the inflected verb, which puts it before the verb *be*.

Comment: But abnormally: ‘I always say that people’s rooms should be clean.’

Comment: I think your rule 2 is wrong. "He always goes away", "We always stop here". In fact I'm hard-pressed to find an example where it _does_ follow an inflected _main_ verb. Agreed that it usually follows a modal.

Comment: Good point, @Colin. On further reflection, this mostly seems to be a rule about *be*: `The light is always on. She is always hungry. That guy is always a jerk.` I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 5):

The first might be grammatical in some dialects, but only the second is grammatical in Standard English (unless it forms part of a sentence beginning, for example, '*They insisted that . . .*')

Comment: Presumably you don't know any of those hypothetical dialects. I certainly don't either, so I think it's best to assume they don't exist, and not mention them at all. If they *do*, you can bet your boots someone will point it out, and you can change your text to reflect that later.

Comment: "[Subject} be..." in the place of "[Subject] is/are..." is commonly heard in AAVE.

Comment: ‘Standard English has irregular forms of the verb “to be” both in the present tense (“am”, “is”, “are”) and in the past (“was”, “were”). Many nonstandard dialects have the same form for all persons, such as “I be”, “you be”, “he be”, “we be”, “they be”.’ (Peter Trudgill. Full text here: http://www.phon.ucl.ac.uk/home/dick/SEtrudgill.htm)

Comment: To supplement onomatomaniak's comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African_American_Vernacular_English#Tense_and_aspect